# Sending argumentsfrom JSF to webflow transitions

Tags: jsf, spring-webflow

Basically what I have now is something like:

```
<view-state id="pageOne" view="pageone.xhtml">
    <transition on="gotoPageTwo" to="doGotoPageTwo" />
</view-state>
<subflow-state id="doGotoPageTwo" subflow="pageTwo">
    <transition on="return" to="pageOne" />
</subflow-state>
```

With the JSF code being:

```
<h:commandLink value="Page Two" action="gotoPageTwo" />
```

So far so good. What I want to do next is something similar to:

```
<h:commandLink value="Page Two" action="gotoPageTwo(customArgument)" />
```

And:

```
<view-state id="pageOne" view="pageone.xhtml">
    <transition on="gotoPageTwo" to="doGotoPageTwo" />
</view-state>
<subflow-state id="doGotoPageTwo" subflow="pageTwo">
    <input name="myCustomArgument" value="customArgument" />
    <transition on="return" to="pageOne" />
</subflow-state>
```

I know this obviously doesn't work as is, but hopefully you get the concept. The only solution I've found is using an actionListener to put the data in some kind of pseudo-global variable (either in a linked bean or in the flash-/flow-Scope). This seems like an ugly decoupled solution, not much different from putting your arguments in global variables instead of passing them in c++. Is there any better way to do this?

Ps. We also use Primefaces but I don't think that's relevant in this situation.